# The class 'Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection' was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using in project Zend Framework 2 with Doctrine 2 ORM. 
I am trying to persist a many to many relation. I followed th documentation described [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) (manytomany).
While trying to persist data: `$em->persist($form->getData());` I got the error:

```
"The class 'Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection' was not found in the chain configured namespaces".
```

Any suggestions ?

To be more clear I added below some code:

First I annotated entities like documentation said, for many to many relation:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\User\Entity\Client", mappedBy="reportSettings")
 */
private $client;

public function __construct() {
    $this->client = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

and

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Statistics\Entity\ReportSettings", inversedBy="client")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="report_client_settings",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="report_setting_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
 */
private $reportSettings;

public function __construct() {
    $this->reportSettings = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

And in the controller

```
$form = new UpdateReportSettingsForm();

    $form->bind($reportSettings);

    $request = new Request();

    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
         $data = $form->getData();
          $em->persist($data); // here I got the error - The class 'Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection' was not found in the chain configured namespaces
          $em->flush();
```

}

I also use in the form DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox.
An simple `var_dump($data)` - return a persistent collection.

Comment: If you'd show us the code, it'd be easier to give you a reasonable answer.

Comment: I added some code. If it's not enough,please tell me and i will add more.

Comment: post your complete entities, the error simply tells that your name space dont have mentioned class included which is kinda vague.

Answer (score 0):

The error appear because the form was not defined correctly. The right way how to do a many to many relation i founded here - http://laundry.unixslayer.pl/2013/zf2-quest-zendform-many-to-many/

Answer (score -1):

Have you added this piece of code in the beginning of your entity where you are mapping

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```

Comment: Well, what you need to persist is your Client Entity, not the data. So fetch the entity 
`$client = new Client();`
check if the form is submitted and if the form is valid then get data
`$data = $form->getData();`
Set the values on the client entity and add the reportSetting Entity to the Client Entity and the finally persist Client Entity
`$em->persist($client);`

Hopefully that helps!!!

Comment: I followed this tutorial - https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md. So by this tutorial there is not needed to set dat if form is defined correctly and doctrine entity is defined with collection.
Is there any good example for many to many - ZF2 and Doctrine 2 ?

Comment: I followed something different, not from a concrete example and there I had setters and getters in the entities for setting and getting the values.

Comment: Sure it's been a while but did you manage to make it work correctly? If so can you please provide solution. It will usefull for others